# SQL SubQuery getting particular column

Tags: sql, mysql

I noticed that there were some threads with similar questions, and I did look through them but did not really get a convincing answer. **Here's my question:**

The subquery below returns a Table with 3 columns, USERNAME, COMPANY, POSITION. I just want to get the USERNAME column out without altering the subquery within. I tried the following:

```
SELECT username from (SELECT username, company, position FROM table1 WHERE username IN (SELECT username FROM members_network WHERE xscore <= 18 AND xscore >= 15))
```

but the outer table is not defined. Can someone tell me how to retrieve only the username from the subquery?

Thanks All!

Comment: What exact error are you getting? That looks fine to me.

Comment: Hi Dan, thx for your reply. The error I am getting is:
#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say which RDBMS you are working with. Some, such as SQL Server, require that in-line views be given a table alias. Unfortunately, I don't have time to start up a windows VM to double check, but you might try:

```
SELECT username 
from (SELECT username, company, position 
    FROM table1 WHERE username IN 
        (SELECT username 
        FROM members_network 
        WHERE xscore <= 18 AND xscore >= 15)) T
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign a table alias to the subquery:

```
SELECT x.username 
  FROM (SELECT username, company, position 
          FROM table1 
         WHERE username IN (SELECT username 
                              FROM members_network 
                             WHERE xscore <= 18 AND xscore >= 15)) x
```

The `x` is the table alias.

Comment: Woops! Deleted. Thanks again Ponies.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment it appears that you need to add aliases on your subqueries. I haven't yet used a database that does this, but I guess some do:

`SELECT username from (SELECT username, company, position FROM table1 WHERE username IN (SELECT username FROM members_network WHERE xscore <= 18 AND xscore >= 15) AS USERNAMES) AS USERDETAILS`

Something like that ought to work (unless your database has funky alias syntax).